# What's the problem with my script?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Why is this giving me `null`?

```
<script language="javascript">
    var element     = "11";
    var string      = "7,11";
    var check       = string.match("/(^|\D)"+element+"(\D|$)/g");
    alert(check);
</script>
```

When I run the `regex` on http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ it works correctly.

*Pleeeease help I want to sleeeep! :))*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var check       = string.match(new RegExp("(^|\\D)"+element+"(\\D|$)", "g"));
```

You have to escape the `\` in the string literal, or the regex engine will see `\D` as `D`.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have read more carefully.  You don't want the `/`es, and you need to handle `/g` separately.

Comment: I escaped it but it's still `null` :|

Comment: Omg!!! omg!! Thanks thanks! I was looking at the error for hours!!! AAaaaAAaaaaAAa, I never seen using regex in this way in javascript before! I love you!!